# Parse string as resource name

Tags: java, android

I have image resources in my `/res` folder for, say, thumbs. Now, I have 30 thumbs and what I do now to initiate array is:

```
Drawable[] thumbs = new Drawable[30];
thumbs[0] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_01);
thumbs[1] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_02);
thumbs[2] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_03);
//this way 27 times more
```

Is there a way to loop this somehow without creating a long array?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. If so, I have a very similar situation in an app I'm developing. What you could do is declare an array of Drawables and add each new Drawable to the array as you loop through each 'thumb' in your resources. I assume there to be a finite number of thumbs since you are retrieving them from your resources. If that's the case, you can also specify in your file that contains the thumbs how many thumbs there are.

```
//assume you assign the number of thumbs to integer 'R.integer.numberofthumbs'
int numberOfThumbs = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numberofthumbs);
Drawable[] thumbs = new Drawable[numberOfThumbs];

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThumbs; i++){
    thumbs[i]= getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("thumb_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

This is essentially the method I use in my code, and it works perfectly. Because of the naming in the for loop your thumbs labeled with numbers under 10 will have to have no leading zero. This could easily be changed to suit your current naming method, however. Hope I'm not too far off and this actually helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `int` array that will hold the values of your drawable resources. Then just loop through this array.

```
int [] array = {R.drawable.thumb_01, R.drawable.thumb_02, ...};
Drawable[] thumbs = new Drawable[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    thumbs[i] = context.getResources().getDrawable(arr[i]);
}
```

**EDIT :**

It seems that your drawables' names follows a certain logic. So you can use [`getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
Drawable[] thumbs = new Drawable[theLength];
Resources r = context.getResources();
for(int i = 0; i < theLength; i++){
    String name = i < 10 ?  "thumb_0"+i : "thumb_"+i;
    int drawableId = r.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    thumbs[i] = r.getDrawable(drawableId);
}
```

Comment: in any case it is necessary to create a large array, the idea is to make a loop for arbitrary number of items, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Roman if you're sure that your drawables names follow a certain logic, you can use `getIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it with less code possible, and without creating array with ints or Drawables.

Create /res/values/array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="thumbs">
    <item>@drawable/thumb_01</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_02</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_03</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_04</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_05</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_06</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_07</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_08</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_09</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_11</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_12</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_13</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_14</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_15</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_16</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_17</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_18</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_19</item>
    <item>@drawable/thumb_20</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

In code

```
TypedArray thumbs = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.thumbs);
//in the loop
image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(thumbs.getResourceId(i, 0));
```